# Olingo JMS integration Synchronous / asynchronous

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, jms, synchronous, olingo

I am looking for a solution for integrating **Apache Oilngo** with **JMS**.
The requirement is to have the client construct HTTP structure and send over socket connection (**Synchronous**) - if HTTP response take more than the specified time period (e.g. 15 minutes), then request gets forwarded to **asynchronous** behavior where the thread will be waiting on the socket for response. Once the response arrives, the original sender gets notified (callback like structure)
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olingo V2 does not have these capabilities. In Olingo V4 there is an asynchronous support available.
Unfortunately there is no documentation on the olingo website about this. So I would suggest you look at the technical service which olingo uses to test  features: https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata4/blob/master/lib/server-tecsvc/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/server/tecsvc/processor/TechnicalEntityProcessor.java#L148

The TechnicalEntityProcessor in the tecsvc module can respond asynchronously. The specification part of this can be found here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398358

Also questions can be asked on the olingo mailing list: user@olingo.apache.org